# Jmeter Concurrency Thread Group, Test plan is not executing as displaying in the Concurrency Thread Group Graph

Tags: performance, concurrency, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am new to Jmeter.

I have a Test Plan with Concurrency Thread Group having the following settings

```
Target Concurrency: 200

Ramp-up Time: 5 min

Ramp-up step count: 10

Hold Target Rate Time: 0

Thread Iteration Limit: 1
```

Throughput Controller as a child to Thread Group with values: Total Execution, throughput 200

5 HTTP request as a child to Throughput Controller.

From what I understood from the graph of Concurrency Tread Group, it will take 5 min to reach the target (200 users) but they are reaching in 2 min and rest of the 3 min test plan is running but nothing is happening. Can anyone tell me the reasons? Is my expectation is wrong? How to create a Test Plan that runs exactly how it shows in the graph?

Comment: If you intend to control throughput, use Constant Throughput Timer. As per JMeter documentation "This controller is badly named, as it does not control throughput. Please refer to the Constant Throughput Timer for an element that can be used to adjust the throughput".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control total executions by using Throughput controller (in your case i believe its 200 executions per user) use  a simple thread group and mention number of users as 200 and give ramp up rate ..

In your [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) enter total executions as 200 (If you want to execute 200 executions per user check per user option in the controller)

I have created and executed a [sample test](https://www.redline13.com/share/testplan/75195) case that executes 2000 executions per user 
If you see the aggregate report the total executions is 2000*10 (2000 executions per user *10 users)= 20000 executions.

For more info on thread groups please read [this article](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/05/guide-jmeter-thread-groups/).

Comment: HI @Rohit, Can u explain how Concurrency Thread Group Works. From the article, u provided & from the graph of Concurrency Thread Grop what I understood is it 1 min for 60 users to hit the server but in 1 min nearly 100 users are hitting the server